# React Native @gorhom/bottom-sheet collapses/opens when keyboard dismiss or input blur

Tags: android, react-native, bottom-sheet, react-native-paper

I have a basic app that uses these packages:

```
"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
"@hookform/resolvers": "^3.0.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
"react-hook-form": "^7.43.8",
"react-native": "0.71.4",
"react-native-paper": "^5.5.2",
```

The problem is that whenever the TextInput focuses then keyboard is dismissed/closed, the bottom sheet appears without triggering it from the ref object.

**Plese note the that TextInput is not inside the BottomSheet**

The sample app has a minimal setup like below:

*App.ts*

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer onReady={RNBootSplash.hide}>
        <PortalProvider>
          <AppNavigator />
        </PortalProvider>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

*AppNavigator.ts*

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Stack.Navigator
                detachInactiveScreens={true}
                screenOptions={{ 
                    animationEnabled: true, 
                    headerShown: false, 
                    cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forScaleFromCenterAndroid 
                }}
                initialRouteName={ScreenRouteEnum.HOME}
            >
                <Stack.Screen name={ScreenRouteEnum.HOME} component={MainScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name={ScreenRouteEnum.ADD_POLE} component={AddPole} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
            <PortalHost name="addPolePortal" />
        </>
    );
};
```

*AddPole.ts*

```
const voltage = [
    {
      pole_voltage_id: 1,
      pole_voltage_name: '69KV'
    }
  ]
  
  
const AddPole = () => {
    const snapPointsVoltage = useMemo(() => ['25%'], []);
     const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

    const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
        (props: any) => (
            <BottomSheetBackdrop
                {...props}
                disappearsOnIndex={-1}
                appearsOnIndex={0}
            />
        ),
        []
    );

    const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
        console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
      }, []);
     
    const onOpenSheet = () => {
       bottomSheetRef?.curret?.collapse();
    }

    return (
            <>
             <TextInput placeholder="Write something" />
             <Button onClick={onOpenSheet}>
                Open Sheet
             </Button>
             <Portal hostName="addPolePortal">
                <BottomSheet
                    ref={bottomSheetRef}
                    index={-1}
                    snapPoints={snapPointsVoltage}
                    enablePanDownToClose
                    onChange={handleSheetChanges}
                    backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
                    handleIndicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#a1a1a1' }}
                >
                    <BottomSheetView style={styles.bottomSheetContainer}>
                        {voltage.map(a => (
                            <TouchableRipple
                                key={a.pole_voltage_id}
                                style={styles.menuItemInner} 
                                rippleColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)" 
                                onPress={onPress}
                              >
                                <Text style={styles.menuText}>{a.pole_voltage_name}</Text>
                            </TouchableRipple>
                        ))}
                    </BottomSheetView>
                </BottomSheet>
             </Portal>
         <>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bottomSheetContainer: {
        paddingVertical: 15,
        flex: 1
    },
})


export default AddPole;
```

I have tried several props specifically for keyboard such as setting `keyboardBlurBehavior="none"` props causeI think this has to be a keyboard-related issue.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, after countless debugging, I've determined what's causing this issue.
It's seems like when the parent component of the `BottomSheet` doesn't have a fixed height

eg: `flex` property is set to `1`,  or
`height` set to `'100%'`, the keyboard breaks the bottom sheet.

In my case, since I am using a `Portal` using `@gorhom/portal` package, I needed to create a `View` to the root of the app and set the height to the height of the device window using `Dimensions`

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}> // I ADDED THIS 
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer onReady={RNBootSplash.hide}>
          <PortalProvider>
            <MainNavigator />
          </PortalProvider>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Note using this fix:**
Although dimensions are available immediately, they may change (e.g due to device rotation) so any rendering logic or styles that depend on these constants should try to call this function on every render, rather than caching the value (for example, using inline styles rather than setting a value in a StyleSheet).

Comment: First of all thanks for the solution. but When I'm using the above code, on the form page form fields automatically do not come above the keyboard. (softInputMode = adjustResize defined in manifest)

Comment: You are a great gentleman

Answer (score 1):

the solution for me was adding this line on BottomSheetModal component: enableDismissOnClose={false}